# Question about work in ship locks

Tags: energy, work

I'm wondering: when water is pumped into a ship lock since the boat is in equilibrium with the water due to buoyant forces, does this mean that the work you do only goes to pumping water level higher but since zero force is on the boat, there is no work needed to lift the boat? I'm having trouble seeing this concept.

Comment: Is water *pumped* into the lock?

Comment: Yes water is being pumped into the locked with a boat in the lock.

Comment: Doesn't it just flow by gravity from the higher level to the lower level?

Comment: It can, however the fill time would be extremely long given reasonably sized pipes so ideally you have a pump that would speed up the process. (I am thinking about large locks)

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly, yes.

Just to clarify, there *is* force on the boat.  It's the [buoyant force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buoyancy), and it's equal magnitude to the weight of the boat (but acting in the other direction, upwards).

When the boat is placed in the water, it does increase the pressure in the water slightly (this is reflected by an increase in water height from the water the boat displaces).

This means that when the boat is in there, the water level is higher already.   Therefore it requires additional pressure to raise the water level.  The presence of the boat increases the amount of work required to add more water.

Comment: Hi, so the work done in raising the boat to a new water level is not just the work to raise the water as if the boat weren't in the lock? How do we take into account the boat being there is what I am curious about.

Comment: @EpsilonSigma The boat itself raises the water level some, and increases the pressure proportionally to its weight.  This means you need to pump in at a higher pressure to account for it.

Comment: Oh I understand now. So does the increase in pressure the boat makes have to do with the area of contact of the boat underside with the water and its weight? And by Pascal's principle this acts in all directions.

Comment: I hope this is not too involved. The reason I asked is I was writing integrals for the work to pump the boat up in a general lock situation. I'm trying to figure out how to account for this pressure of the boat in my work equation.

Comment: @EpsilonSigma The increase in pressure would be the weight of the boat over the horizontal area of the channel.  Somewhat related, are the pumps usually even submerged, or do they use pumps above the water level?  Because pumping above the water level removes this consideration, at the expense of always having to pump up to a set pressure.

Comment: In my conceptual design I am placing a pump at the water level (with boat in lock). In this way when the boat is positioned in the lock, the water line is at the same level as the pump so you can fill the lock above this line to transfer the ship to the next height. Now you're probably thinking, why not just keep the pump at a high height, but I am placing it so the lock can be reset by pumping water back out from that level via two pumps. In this way new ships can go into the lock and be transferred.

Comment: However, you just got me thinking. I could always have a pump higher up to fill the lock. And one at water level to drain the lock! Then, I would need to know the work to drain the lock back to that water level. I imagine it would be the same as to fill it up.